# react nested component pass builtin function (no flux)

Tags: reactjs, this, virtual-dom

I'm trying to pass built in react function through props and trying to set state but I get `this` as undefined!

I've tried something like this:

**index.js**

```
let somefun = function(){
    this.setState({myvar:1});
}

ReactDom.render(<someComponent body={<someOtherComponent1 componentWillUpdate={somefun}/>} />, document.getElementById('someValidID'));
```

**someOtherComponent1.js**

```
React.createElement( someOtherComponent1, { "className": "someclass"} )
```

My Problem is whenever I pass a builtin function ie, functions present in react prototype `this` is always undefined.

**How can I send built-in functions through props?**

Answer (score 1):

Very common problem with getting familiar with `this` and passing functions around.

**tl;dr** in order to call `setState` on `this`, `this` needs to be called inside the component whose state needs to be updated. You're calling it outside of the component.

**someFun** is a new function that calls a function of `this` inside it. The problem is that in that context, `this` is a reference to `someFun` and not your component instance. Go ahead and put a `console.log(this)` in there to see.

I think in your scenario `onComponentWillUpdate` should be a function inside of your component, not declared outside of it.

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <someOtherComponent1 onComponentWillUpdate={function(nextProps, nextState) {
       // do something here
      }}
    />
  )
```

But, don't forget you have to actually call that function in your child component.

```
// in someOtherComponent1
componentWillUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  // do something
  this.props.onComponentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer...but I'm trying to work out some abstraction here.. I don't want to set the sumeFunc inside the component...the reason is,, this component is a reusable component and the only thing that isdynamic to this component is `componentWillUpdate` func so, I was looking for a way to specify it from outside the component (pass it down from the parent component or something similar) habe you got any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: It would work like this. As long as your component always calls the function passed down (you could even name it onComponentWillMount to make it more understandable), it will work. What you're wanting is the older React's mixins methodology, but those are supported anymore. Keep in mind you can define the onComponentWillMount on the fly. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReactDom.render(<someComponent body={<someOtherComponent1 yourFn={somefun}/>} />, document.getElementById('someValidID'));
```

and inside component

```
this.props.yourFn()
```

Comment: This won't work because the issue is that `someFun` doesn't have the right pointer to `this`, so renaming and calling it in the child component will do the same thing. It needs to be defined inside the instance of the component, so that `this` points to the component. As it stands now, it's being declared outside of the component.